# Regex to find strings containing substring, but not ending on same substring

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that checks if a string contains the substring "ing", but it most not end on "ing".

So the word sing would not work but singer would.

I think I have figured out how to make sure that the string does not end with ing, for that I'm using

```
(!<?(ing))$
```

But I can't seem to get it to work when I want the word to contain "ing" as well. I was thinking something like

```
(\w+(ing))(!<?(ing))$
```

But that does not work, all of my solution that sort of makes it work will take in more than one word as well. So it will match *singer* but not *singer crafting*, it should still match singer here, just not crafting.

Comment: Why not just use `ing.+$`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the pattern:

```
ing(?=\w)
```

This would only be true for words which contain `ing` which is also followed by another word character.  Here is an example:

```
inp = 'singer'
if re.search(r'ing(?=\w)', inp):
    print('singer is a MATCH')

inp = 'sing'
if re.search(r'ing(?=\w)', inp):
    print('sing is a MATCH')
```

This prints:

```
singer is a MATCH
```

**Edit:**

To match entire words containing non terminal `ing`, I suggest using `re.findall`:

```
inp = "Madonna is a singer who likes to sing."
matches = re.findall(r'\b\w*ing\w+\b', inp)
print(matches)    # prints ['singer']
```

Comment: Great solution, but the matches will only be 'ing' not singer. I presented the issue poorly but i need to match the entire word not only the ing

Comment: Your answer covers that edge case and I won't poach your stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If the word can not end with ing but must contain ing:

```
\b\w*ing(?!\w*ing\b)\w+
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\w*` Match 0+ word characters
- `ing` Match the required `ing`
- `(?!\w*ing\b)` Negaetive lookahead, assert the `ing` is not at the end of the word
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars so that there must be at least a single char following

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Cd9Ij/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/SDCWhy)

For example

```
import re

items = ["singer","singing","ing","This is a ing testing singalong"]
pattern = r"\b\w*ing(?!\w*ing$)\w+\b"

for item in items:
    result = re.findall(pattern, item)
    if result:
        print(result)
```

Output

```
['singer']
['singalong']
```

Comment: Good and complete answer +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I was just wondering, maybe I read the question wrong. You have my vote :-)

Comment: Actually, if we take the title into consideration ("*find strings containing substring, but not ending on same substring*") this is the only correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('\w*ing\w+')
print(pattern.match('sing'))  # No match
print(pattern.match('singer')) # Match
```

Comment: That will match `singing`

Comment: Ah, thats correct. Thanks for pointing out @Thefourthbird